# How to define a transient field in Ecto?

Tags: elixir, ecto

How do I define a transient field in Ecto, i.e. a field that will **not** be persisted along the rest of the schema?

I searched everywhere including the documentation and can't find anything referring to this terminology.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ecto uses a different terminology for transient field, `:virtual`, as defined in the [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#field/3):

```
field :password, :string, virtual: true
```

Comment: Off-topic: I have never understood the use of colons in Elixir. Some places they are before the text, some places after.

Comment: @HrishikeshChoudhari the colon is before an atom, and there is a special syntax for keyword list, `[{:virtual, true}]` can also be written as `[virtual: true]`, and as the last parameter of a function call, you can even omit the `[]`. See https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/basic-types.html#atoms and https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/keywords-and-maps.html